# Inner join doesn't work in Slick

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, slick

Could you please tell me why I'm not getting inner join I'm expecting to get ?

I have following tables

```
case class Ability(id: UUID, can: Boolean, verb: String, subject: String, context: String)

object Abilities extends Table[Ability]("abilities"){
  def id = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def can = column[Boolean]("is_can")
  def verb = column[String]("verb")
  def subject = column[String]("subject")
  def context = column[String]("context")

  def * = id ~ can ~ verb ~ subject ~ context <> (Ability, Ability.unapply _)
}

case class Role(id: UUID, name : String)

object Roles extends Table[Role]("roles"){
  def id = column[UUID]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name")

  def * = id ~ name <> (Role, Role.unapply _)
}

// And join table
case class AbilityRelationship(owner_id: UUID, obj_id: UUID, is_role: Boolean)

object AbilitiesMapping extends Table[AbilityRelationship]("abilities_mapping"){
  def owner_id = column[UUID]("owner_id")
  def obj_id = column[UUID]("obj_id")
  def is_role = column[Boolean]("is_role")

  def * = owner_id ~ obj_id ~ is_role <> (AbilityRelationship, AbilityRelationship.unapply _)
}
```

What I'm willing to do is to fetch list of `Ability` objects for particular owner (whether user or role). So following documentation I wrote following join query for it

```
val some_id = role.id
val q2 = for {
  a <- Abilities
  rel <- AbilitiesMapping
  if rel.owner_id === some_id.bind
} yield (a)
```

But `q2.selectStatement` returns absolutely wrong query for it. Which is `select x2."id", x2."is_can", x2."verb", x2."subject", x2."context" from "abilities" x2, "abilities_mapping" x3 where x3."owner_id" = ?` in my case.

How should it be implemented?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, after multiple attempts I made it

```
  val innerJoin = for {
    (a, rel) <- Abilities innerJoin AbilitiesMapping on (_.id === _.obj_id) if rel.owner_id === some_id.bind
  } yield a
```

But man... typesafe's documentation is really really weak for newcomers.

Comment: important to use if instead of adding it to the on condition

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
val q2 = for {
  a <- Abilities
  rel <- AbilitiesMapping
  if a.id == rel.obj_id && rel.owner_id === some_id.bind
} yield (a)
```

BTW, you know you can annotate your foreign keys in the Table objects right?

Comment: But I don't need any information from `Role` in my case. I have its id in `some_id`.

Comment: Now I see what you wanted. I will rewrite my query.

Comment: Yep, I can annotate foreign keys but I'm not sure I can do it in my case using Slick because foreign key may refer to different objects depending on `is_role`.

Answer (score 1):

Tried doing this as a comment to ruslan's answer, but I just dont have enough jedi powers:

Can you try if this desugar-ed version works?

```
val rightSide = AbilitiesMapping.filter(_.owner_id === some_id)    
val innerJoin = (Abilities innerJoin (rightSide) on (
  (l,r) => (l.id === r.obj_id)
).map { case (l, r) => l }
```